# In a ChessBase opening tree how can we put a column that displays the percent of time each move is played or a column that displays "Perf" minus "Av"?

Tags: opening, engines, software, database, chessbase

Here are the columns displayed in an opening tree on ChessBase 12:

[image]

I would be interested in adding two columns:

- A column which displays the percent of time each move is played in the position.
  So for the starting position it should display something like that: 1.e4 42% - 1.d4 40% - 1.Nf3 9% - 1.c4 6% - etc.
- A column which displays "Perf" minus "Av".
  "Av" is the average Elo before the game has started of the players who played that move. "Perf" is the average Elo after the game has ended of the players who played that move.
  So "Perf" minus "Av" is equal to the average Elo one is expected to gain by playing that move.
  In my opinion "Perf" minus "Av" is even more useful than the average score (the percent of time White wins plus half the percent of time it ends in a draw). And it takes me a lot of time to calculate and remember them every time.

Comment: I would be interested too in displaying Perf-Av.
You can try to modify Scid source code and recompile it, but it's not an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in ChessBase 12.

Comment: I see that this answer has received a downvote and a close vote. I invite suggestions for improving it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use one of ChessBase's chess playing programs like "Fritz" to display additional statistical information. In this example the column "Prob" gives the general probability for each move of a specific position while the column "[%]" shows the actual preference of a chess engine to play the move from the openings book. The engine preference can be tweaked based on variety of play and influence of learning value.

[image]